# IdentityServer3 - Exception handling

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

Is there a way to handle exceptions ourselves.  We have custom user service code inside our identityserver project and would like to know without diving through logs when errors occur.

We have a centralized error logger for all our apps.  I'd imagine something similar needed if using 3rd party exception lib (airbrake etc).

Is there something possible at the moment or is this ticket solving my problem
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you care about the error logging - the event service will log all unhandled exceptions.

The issue you mentioned would allow you to have more control over direct error handling (e.g. setting a custom http response) - but that's backlog right now.